# Soft Keyboard - Numeric Only

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, numeric

my question is kinda related to this question: [Numeric Soft Keyboard on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216169/numeric-soft-keyboard-on-android)

BUT, the question above isnt answered, so here i am.

Theres a EditText that when it gets touched or has focus, i want the Software Keyboard to show up by default as NUMERIC! Of course, you can switch back to ALPHANUMERIC, but i want to force it to show up as NUMERIC.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`android:inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) XML attribute with the `number` value:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edtInput"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"/>
```

Comment: I'm gonna try it! Thank you Cristian!