# EditText with number keypad by default, but allowing alphabetic characters

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have an EditText box and I want the default keyboard that comes up when it is selected to be the numeric keypad, since **most of the time** users will be entering numbers. However, I do want to allow users to enter alphabetic characters too, if they need to. Using `android:inputType="number"` restricts input to numeric digits only. What options do I have?

Comment: Hi have you got the solution ?If yes then please share it.I have to implement the same

Comment: Do you want user to start with numeric only and then after more than 1 digit he/she can allow to enter alphanumeric?

Comment: this have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8776491/1529129)

Comment: possible duplicate.
question answered in this [Similar Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134873/android-display-numeric-keypad-on-button-click)

Answer (score 21):

Define your EditText in your xml this way:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtOppCodigoCliente"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLength="11"
    android:hint="@string/strCodigoCliente"/>
```

output:
   [android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpLho.jpg)

A row of numbers and the rest of letters.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer!

Comment: It depends on the keyboard. In my case does not work with the last versions of Google Keyboard and Nougat.

Comment: Did you fixed the problem

Comment: this._editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        this._editText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);  works for me

Comment: @fireb86 it does work with the latest version of Gboard. And its working perfectly fine on Oreo.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest a more Robust solution:

Present the user with the ability to choose the input type:

***NEEDED FIXES***

-*better handling of showing/hiding the input selection buttons*

-*probably remove the suggestions when the input type is letter*

[image]

Here is the activity:

```
package mobi.sherif.numberstexttextview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText mEdit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        mEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
                findViewById(R.id.llmenu).setVisibility(focused?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onNumbers(View v) {
        mEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    }

    public void onLetters(View v) {
        mEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }

}
```

Here is the activity's xml : `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llmenu" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonnumbers"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onNumbers"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Numbers" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonletters"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onLetters"
            android:text="Letters" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If number is one of the inputTypes and the keyboard is in fullscreen mode (landscape), letters get hidden. When switching back to the TEXT inputType, they appear again.

Answer (score 10):

**Here is what you are looking for:**

Define your `EditText` in your xml this way:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hint">

</EditText>
```

And call following in your `onCreate()`:

```
etTest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTest);
etTest.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
// Note the "Raw"
```

Whenever you click into your `EditText` now, you can enter **digits AND letters**! (Digit keyboard is shown first)

Comment: For me on a Nexus 7 it showed the numeric pad but it had no way of showing the normal keyboard.

Comment: Looked promising, but if number is one of the inputTypes and the keyboard is in fullscreen mode (landscape), letters get hidden.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because only one inputType can be set for an EditText. The following will just show alphabatic characters on buttons.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|number" />
```

However, what I can suggest you is, set your input type to numeric, and just add a small switchKeyboard button on your form close to the numpad. And set its onClick

```
editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

so that users can switch to alphabetic characters, too.

Comment: Reason for that lies in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) Take a close look at the constant names. You only can combine one class with one variation and one flag. Like `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED`. **But you never can mix classes like `number` and `text`**

Comment: the documentation certainly does not state that classes cannot be mixed. there's no lint check complaining about it. and there's even a specific keyboard when combining eg `number|text` (see above) which implies you could enter letters via long press, doesn't actually work. looks rather buggy to me, or incomplete at least.

Comment: @masc3d - agreed doc doesn't say that where it should. Is mentioned under [InputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType), in description of `TYPE_MASK_CLASS`: 
Mask of bits that determine the overall class of text being given. supported classes are: TYPE_CLASS_TEXT, TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER, TYPE_CLASS_PHONE, TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME.
IME authors: If the class is not one you understand, assume TYPE_CLASS_TEXT with NO variation or flags."

Answer (score 6):

Basically, EditText inputtype is used to **set the input type** in your EditText.

The possible values for the `android:inputtype` are:

- text
- textCapCharacters
- textCapWords
- textCapSentences
- textAutoCorrect
- textAutoComplete
- textMultiLine
- textImeMultiLine
- textNoSuggestions
- textUri
- textEmailAddress
- textEmailSubject
- textShortMessage
- textLongMessage
- textPersonName
- textPostalAddress
- textPassword
- textVisiblePassword
- textWebEditText
- textFilter
- textPhonetic
- number
- numberSigned
- numberDecimal
- phone
- datetime
- date
- time

then you can use any value as showing in example:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:inputType="number"
 android:text="1212223"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't even find the Google Android documentation, listing all of this!

Answer (score 4):

Asus tablet has that feature, they have customized the default keyboard. And the keyboard contains the numbers and alphabets only. I think your requirement solution is too to customize the default keyboard

Answer (score 3):

You should not use any inputType filter in this case, just add the below line in your EditText Property

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "
```

Now only these characters will be allowed to enter in the EditText.
The complete code of your edittext will be like this:

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/etTest"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10"
 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "
 android:hint="@string/hint">
```

Comment: Perfect solution ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can follow Paresh Mayani answer.

And in advice you can use `android:inputType="textPhonetic"` for the inputType Text and Number based on user selection.

Hope you will got my point.

Answer (score 2):

In OnCreate in Activity do this:

```
    t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.test);
    t.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == 67) { // Handle backspace button =)
                if (text.length() > 0) {
                    t.setText(text.subSequence(0, text.length() - 1));
                    t.setSelection(text.length()-1);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getInputType() {
            return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        }

        @Override
        public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {

        }
    });
```

In this case you type is `number` and android will show numeric keyboard, but you can input whatever you want.
Also you can override other methods as you wish.

Comment: Did you try it in landscape, when the keyboard is in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I achieved it...

android:inputType="textPhonetic|numberDecimal"
android:digits="/0123456789.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Only characters specified by digits will be allowed.

Please note that the keyboard shown is that of the dialer, not the typical keyboard.  For me, it achieved what I needed to entirely within the XML.

Comment: Don't mix input classes. They always will result in number. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters/28694835#comment46661555_14476449

Comment: Thanks slamn, I needed to use only whole numbers and "-"/minus operator

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically it is possible with little bit of tweak to the usual flow.
First you have to set editText as:

`editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

Then you have to listen for keyevent.
On pressing of pound set the InputType again to InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT.
This should work as it works for me.

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
{
     @Override
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.d("KeyBoard", "Keyboard Test Key Hit");

        switch (keyCode) 
        {
              KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND:

              if(editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
              {                             
                   editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                   return true;
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: is it a java code? Also, some keyboards, when in TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER, don't have a KEYCODE_POUND button.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have a toggle button that either:

- Sets the input type to allow only numerical values
- Sets the input type to allow the use of the QWERTY keyboard
- Or set other input types (if needed)

That way, you can set the numeric keypad to default, then the user can change it by pressing a button.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible** given current default Android input types across various phones.

There are many possible hacks that **work on some keyboards but not on others**, like the common method of setting the raw input type that is commonly included in answers:

- `editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)`

---

Best advice I could find is to use the `textPostalAddress` input type in your XML:

- `android:inputType="textPostalAddress"`

Unfortunately this doesn't do what we want it to do *yet*, but *maybe it will in the future*. The only advantage of this is that the meta information on your edit box will reflect what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting---

```
editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);
```

for [more description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772860/1099156)

Comment: Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY == InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER == 2

Answer (score 0):

In your code for textView, remove the "text" in android:inputType.

It should be,

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

Comment: This is not solving his problem. He wants to allow letters and numbers with numbers keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programatically:

```
// Numbers
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

// Text
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

> setInputType(int type) Set the type of the content with a constant as
>   defined for inputType.

Answer (score 0):

As Saurav says, the best way is changing between QWERTY Keyboard and Numeric Keyborad with a simple listener:

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (keyCode) {
        case 24: // Volumen UP

             input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
             break;
         case 25: // Volumen DOWN

             input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
             break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I try all the method but not perfect.
So I have another idea. Work perfect for all keyboard.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);
    editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (editText.isFocused()) {
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        }

    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (editText.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) {
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your xml layout for EditText add this parameter:

```
android:inputType="number|text"
```

This will allow the user to enter both text and number and contains the logic in the xml rather than having code in your activity or fragment.

Comment: Don't mix input classes. They always will result in number. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters/28694835#comment46661555_14476449