# android EditText inputType for StreetNumber field

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I'm trying to choose correct inputType in my adress dialog  streetNumber field.
 I want to show numeric keyboard first, but then let user also to input alphabetic characters
 for some very special cases. Closer to this is inputType  datetime,
  but this doesn't allow to enter alphabetic characters. So how to set my streetNumber field correctly?

Comment: There are lots of answers to this on many related posts, but unfortunately *it is not currently possible* using `inputType` or `setRawInputType()` if you want your code to work on "most devices"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText with number keypad by default, but allowing alphabetic characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters)

Answer (score 5):

Use  `android:inputType="textPostalAddress"`

Comment: Your postal address contains number as well as text so best option for address is  android:inputType="textPostalAddress" but if you don't want a text keyboard then you can set only number keyboard

Comment: so have can I set showing number keyboard first with combination with inputType:textPostalAddress?

Comment: You can not use keyboard with combination you have only one choice if you want to use both text and number in postal address or you can use android:inputType="text"

Answer (score 0):

The `EditText` inherits from `TextView` and shares its input type attributes with it. They can be found [here in the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).

Maybe the input type `textPostalAddress` would be suitable for your need. If not, plenty of other types are available. The XML attribute that allows setting this type is `android:inputType="the type you have chosen"`.

Comment: that's the problem I went through all type and couldn't find nothing that exactly match my requests

Answer (score -3):

See if this can help you

```
myEditText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY)
```

Comment: this can help me showing numeric keyboard first? yeah it realy works!

Comment: This works on both my samsung galaxy and moto droid. It does not, however work on Galaxy Tab. Still haven't figured it out why?

Comment: oh I just tryed it on Galaxy Tab, and this can't be used, we have to probably find something else...

Comment: I've got this working with a combination of Input type and TextWatcher

Comment: This "works" because the value of Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY is 2, which is the value of inputType.numberDecimal.  I was expecting postalAddress input type to first show number input, then after the space show characters.  But it doesn't work.