# Numeric keyboard as default

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EditText with number keypad by default, but allowing alphabetic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters)

I have an EditText where user can enter both numbers (0 - 9) and characters (a -z, what ever).  But I would like to set the numeric soft-keyboard as default. I want the numeric keyboard appearing first, but user can press the [ABC] button  and enter what ever character he wants.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, if you use `inputType="phone" / inputType="number"` you cannot switch back to the text keyboard. This is not exclusive to tablets or any specific version of the Android OS.

A workaround would be to change it programmatically using [setInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29). You would have to implement it in a way that best suits your application.

Comment: Can you help me? How can I implement it for my way?

Comment: Hmm. You could always put a button by the EditText to act as a switch for [ABC] keypad or [123]. Set the inputType based on whether they're switching from [ABC] to [123] and vice versa. Just think of the best logical way you can implement it in your application that would make it easy for the user to utilize.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the EditText to include:

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

Which is only the numpad

or

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Which also allows characters, but starts on the number keyboard.

Comment: You're wrong. From SDK: android:inputType="number" A numeric only field. Corresponds to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL.

Comment: Did you try it? I mean it pops up with the alternative characters, which has the numbers. I just tested it myself and it worked fine, maybe you should be more clear on what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes I try it on galaxy tab (Android 3.1). Only digits are available.

Comment: Ahh you should have mentioned this was for a tablet. I'll look into it.