# Android software keyboard switch between numeric and alphabetic programmatically

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an EditText with **inputMode = text**. By default software keyboard is shown as alphabetical and user have to switch it to numeric by pressing specific key (like "123").

Having **text** inputMode is it possible to show numeric keyboard by default instead of alphabetic?

I need both alphabetic and numeric. But numeric is used  more often then alphabetic so i search for way to switch mode programmatically.

Comment: I gone rather feel stupid asking this, but why dont you change android:inputType="number" when you obviously expect some number and no alphabet characters?

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer a day, finally I found this and its work.

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296490/5327495)

Answer (score 1):

Just set it with the normal setter:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    // or 
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Comment: This sets the type of input to numbers and only numbers. The goal is to allow both numbers and characters, only set the keyboard mode to numbers by default.

Answer (score -3):

you can achieve it by setting the below attribute to EditText on xml has follows `android:inputType="number"`