# Android: Set alphanumeric keyboard to show numeric first in EditText

Tags: android

I'm implementing an Android App and I need a tip. My `EditText`, usually, is just numbers, but sometimes numbers and letters.

This is the keyboard that I need as "default", when the `EditText` is focused:

[image: numeric keyboard]

If I put `android:inputType="phone"` or `android:inputType="number"`, the result isn't what I need:

[image: phone layout keyboard]

I need numbers and letters. So, is it possible to do? I already tried EVERY `inputType`. I try to "mix" some `inputType`s, like, `number | text`, but nothing changes.

Comment: Add relevant code that you have and you will find that help comes easier

Comment: OK, but there isn't a relevant code... it's a simple EditText in xml layout file.

Comment: You need to display letters and numbers? without switching the layout?

Comment: I guess I don't understand where the problem is then. I thought you had the layouts and were having trouble switching programatically which would require code

Comment: Ahmad and codeMagic, I need to display the first image. Imagine that I focused one EditText, will show a keyboard with letters. So, I need to click in ?123 at the bottom left, to show numbers (the first image from my question), ok? So, what I'm trying to do is: when I focus the EditText show the numbers, without any click. BUT I need to be able to switch to letters, so android:inputType="number" doesn't work in my case, because if I do, I can't "back" to letters.

Comment: Hi Beneti, i wanna do this in my application, any progress in this problem? Please suggest if you got the solution

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702557/5327495)

Answer (score -2):

If you want a general keyboard you can use this:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

This will allow you to use default keyboard with all the special characters, numerics and alphabets one needs.

*Looking at the date when this question was asked no doubt it was a hassle to feed the type of keyboard desired. Anyways, if you are still tracking this question. Here's the answer.*

Comment: That's not what is being asked, please read the question title.

Answer (score -3):

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

Above code must need **1.5 or up version**
if its not working also try

```
EditText num = new EditText(this);
num.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: As I said, doesn't work, for me. The result of android:inputType="number" is the second image.