# Android 3.2 InputType Number Preselection

Tags: android, text, numbers, android-edittext

I have an EditText-Object in my Android App where the user can input a "street number". Because street number may also consit of characters, character input should not be disabled at all, rather it numeric input should just be **preselected** and if the user wants he can also **switch to character input**.
Until now I could not find any combination of Flags using

```
editText.setInputType(...);
```

Possible allowed entries in the EditText would be:
**23a-26b**

This always disallows some other input type, but what I want is just a preselected inputType.

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean you just want to input nos and characters in the edit text

Comment: yes, and i want that numeric input is the pre-selected method.

Comment: There are lots of answers to this on many related posts, but unfortunately *it is not currently possible* using `inputType` or `setRawInputType()` if you want your code to work on "most devices"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText with number keypad by default, but allowing alphabetic characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters)