# want to show numeric soft input keyboard in default alphabetic keybord

Tags: android, android-keypad

i have many input fields in my project and all of them accept numeric values followed by alphabetic values(like 246736adsf) so i want to show numeric keyboard first(in keyboard having numeric and alphabetic values) and alphabetic on selection. I tried a lot but all problems open only numeric not combination of both. So please help me to get rid of this problem. Thanking you.

Comment: This has already been asked a lot:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters

Comment: can we achieve this in xml field of EditText

Comment: Please read the full article.

Comment: @sebastian it is showing keyboard like numeric. i have checked it

Answer (score -1):

set input type to number for edit text like this

```
    android:inputType="number"
```

UPDATE

```
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Comment: may i know why down vote???

Comment: please read my question again. if i use android:inputType="number" then i am not able to input alphabets and i want both but numeric first

Comment: @curious_mid thank you it almost solved my problem. but i am still not able to select alphabets in keyboard.