# Edittext is not accepting number as input type

Tags: android, android-edittext

I cannot enter number (numeric) in the Edittext field.

If I keep `android:inputType="text"`, number cannot be entered.
If I keep `android:inputType="text|number"`, the keyboard accepts only digits.

But If I keep `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`, I can enter both text/number but the first character cannot be number and it should be a character.

And I tried doing with other options too, nothing worked. I'm building the application with the `target sdk:21`

Note: I need both text / number as input

Answer (score 1):

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
  public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
      for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
        if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
            return ""; 
        }
      }
      return null; 
    } 
}; 
your_edit_text.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: Pl add some explanation to your answer

Comment: @SahilMittal You just replace your edittext instance with 'your_edit_text',its Only allow the user to enter numerics.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isLeadingDigit(final String value){
    final char c = value.charAt(0);
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: I think this'll help you  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters/28694835#comment46661555_14476449]

Answer (score 0):

Try to not specify inputType or set it to "none" if you want to be able to enter text and numbers.