# How do I default to numeric keyboard on EditText without forcing numeric input?

Tags: android, android-keypad

This has been asked elsewhere online to no avail. Is there any way in Android to display the numeric soft keyboard when focusing on an `EditText`, but still allow any text to be entered?

I'd like to let the user enter quantities (e.g. "1 kg", "2 L"), so just setting `inputType="number"` won't work.

Comment: There are lots of answers to this on many related posts, but unfortunately *it is not currently possible* using `inputType` or `setRawInputType()` if you want your code to work on "most devices"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add the following line of code, and it will do the trick :)

`editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);`

This will show the the numeric keypad first, but also allows you to enter free text.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772860/607968).

Comment: it doesn't work with all the soft keyboards.

Comment: exact, not working on samsung s3 mini and s4

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, the setRawInputType function expects values from InputType not Configuration. It just so happens that Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY is 2 and InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER is also 2.

Comment: This answer is completely invalid! Solution does not work, and Configuration class constants are not appropriate for setRawInputType.

Comment: this worked for me with the default google keyboard at least. maybe not valid for third party ones.  I used this way back in 2012 in the days of honeycomb, and when the most popular OS was gingerbread. Maybe things have changed after ICS.

Comment: This is not the expected one.

Comment: Didn't worked on Nexus.

Answer (score 8):

This may be device dependant but have you tried:

```
 android:inputType="phone"
```

[All Input Types Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

in the EditText's xml , this gives you the number pad keyboard but then you can still switch to letter's if you want. (Atleast on my Nexus One).

Comment: If you specify inputType="number" you can also switch to letters, but pressing on letters has no effect. If I set inputType="phone", I cannot even switch to letters on my device, never mind actually typing text. Can you type letters into your phone field?

Answer (score 7):

Note that: setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

has the desired effect on some devices but not others...

On htc it works fine however on galaxy tab II you only get the numeric keyboard and no way to switch back to alpha.

Answer (score 4):

write the code in XML,
           android:numeric="integer"
           android:inputType="phone"
       android:digits="1234567890"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the underlying question you're dealing with is: how can I allow the user to enter quantities?

One appropriate answer is: with a numeric input, paired with some form of category select for the unit. e.g. radio, dropdown, or spinner. This is probably easier to use and also saves you the headache of having to validate your input every time.

You could also just have iron cojones and write a custom soft keyboard.

Comment: Custom Keyboard - the only available solution really.

Answer (score -1):

I tried many different combinations before I figured this out, but this appears to work correctly:

```
setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

The key lies in the description for [`setRawInputType(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType%28int%29):

> Directly change the content type integer of the text view, *without
>   modifying any other state*.

Comment: Same as Mark's answer. Doesn't work on all devices