# Show numeric keyboard first when input type is "text"

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I would like to display **Numberic** keyboard to the user first even though my `AutoCompleteTextView`'s **input type** is **text**.

I read this [How do I default to numeric keyboard on EditText without forcing numeric input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153796/how-do-i-default-to-numeric-keyboard-on-edittext-without-forcing-numeric-input) question and tried to fix it. But it is only showing **numeric** keyboard. It won't allow me to input **Text**.

I would like to **show first** "numberic" input but also allow to enter "text" to `AutoCompleteTextView`. Any solution?

**Edit**

I am using Galaxy Tab 2 with 4.0.4 OS Version

When screen launch, following keyboard appears.

[image]

But I want to switch keyboard to "numeric" input (which appears when we press "123" button)

[image]

Comment: one doubt: in numeric keyboard how "abcd" letters i mean text will appears?

Comment: @mtetno i edited my question. can you please refer it again..

Comment: i guess u need to set input type..to "numberPassword"

Comment: But how can i do that? I also require to allow user for input of alphabetic. If i set "numeric", user is not allowed to input alphabetic.

Comment: @mtetno nope.. numberPassword will not allow user to enter alphabetic characters.

Comment: discuss in chat ?http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o