# prefered input type EditText

Tags: android

I create dynamically an EditText.
For the forced inpt type with numbers ill use  `.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

Now I want only the prefered input type is numbers, but characters are allowed. The keyboard popup should first show the numberpad. Is that possible?

thanks

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153796/how-do-i-default-to-numeric-keyboard-on-edittext-without-forcing-numeric-input

Comment: you read the link?there is no correct answer, which works on all devices.

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog thats good post, thank you