# Soft keyboard for numbers that allows entering letters

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there an [`InputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) for (default) Android soft keyboards that is targeted at entering numbers but also allows entering letters?

This would be for an input fields like the house number, that most of the time contains only numbers, but sometimes also letters.

On iOS, there is `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation` that displays the normal keyboard, but with the page that contains the numbers; you can then switch back to the letter page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I default to numeric keyboard on EditText without forcing numeric input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153796/how-do-i-default-to-numeric-keyboard-on-edittext-without-forcing-numeric-input)

Comment: possible duplicate of [EditText with number keypad by default, but allowing alphabetic characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such things in Android.

You should take a lokk at the official documentation : [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL)

Answer (score 1):

InputType `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS` seems closest to what you need.

if you want to start with a numeric keyboard initially and then want to switch to qwerty [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8776491/1529129) might help you.