# Compose TextField with number keypad by default, but allowing alphabetic characters

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a numeric keyboard by default but let the user change it to text.

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
)
```

I read a lot of old questions and answers but none of them were helpful, including:

[How do I default to numeric keyboard on EditText without forcing numeric input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153796/how-do-i-default-to-numeric-keyboard-on-edittext-without-forcing-numeric-input?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

[EditText with number keypad by default, but allowing alphabetic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters)

Comment: How user change it to text, if you only allowed numeric keyboard? You can change the keyboard type whenever you want.

Comment: You have to do something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586341/9636037.  Change the input type based on user selection.

Comment: That is not supported out-of-the-box by android. You'll need to create your own keyboard if you wish to implement this feature. There's no other way so I wouldn't recommend wasting your time looking for out-of-the-box solutions to your problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward solution. So, I decided to implement it myself:

```
var keyboardType by remember { mutableStateOf(KeyboardType.Number) }
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = keyboardType),
    trailingIcon = {
        if (keyboardType == KeyboardType.Number) {
            Icon(
                painterResource(
                    id = if (keyboardType == KeyboardType.Number)
                        R.drawable.ic_abc_24
                    else
                        R.drawable.ic_pin_24
                ),
                contentDescription = "Change keyboard",
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    keyboardType = if (keyboardType == KeyboardType.Number)
                        KeyboardType.Text
                    else
                        KeyboardType.Number
                }
            )
        }
    }
)
```