# Custom keyboard - Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-custom-view, android-keypad

Is there any known combinations of `inputTypes` on an `inputText` that would give a Num-pad keyboard with special characters such as `$`, `*`, `#` and `&`. I am trying to allow the user to input a number and that field could take the mentioned characters as well. I have tried many but none seem to be giving the required output.

Would I have to create my own custom keyboard for this? Since my request is very specific to certain special characters please do not mark this as a duplicate question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) to for customizing as your need.

```
KeyboardView customKeyboard = new KeyboardView(context);
customKeyboard.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this, R.xml.customLayout));

customKeyboard.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {
    //do your work here
}
```

Where **R.xml.customLayout** refers to **/res/xml/customLayout.xml**. A very good tutorial for customizing a keyboard is..

- [create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html)

Which will help you much better.

Comment: Is it possible to show the number keyBoard by default the same that comes up when i click on the number option on the existing keyBoard

Comment: try with editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY). More information from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216169/numeric-soft-keyboard-on-android/3772860#3772860