# how to show the soft keyboard with numbers first in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want the keyboard to appear in following format.

I just tried all the available solutions but none of them is working for my *soft keyboard*.I want a solution for this.

I used the *Keyboard Qwerty* and *input type* options.

Comment: Please post your screen shot

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216169/numeric-soft-keyboard-on-android/3772860#3772860

Comment: where is"following format" ? Please add format description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using EditText Then use in layout

```
 android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

in android manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the inputType of your EditText to number..

```
<EditText android:inputType = "number|text"..../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your code (where "input" is your EditText) :

```
input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```