# Digit keyboard by default but allowing alphabetic characters

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an `EditText` box and I want the default keyboard that comes up when it is selected to be the numeric keypad. However, I do want to allow users to enter alphabetic characters too. The solutions `android:inputType="number"` ,  `et.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)`...etc does not work for me because restricts input to numeric digits only. Does someone know some solution??

Comment: Please check this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544214/edittext-with-number-keypad-by-default-but-allowing-alphabetic-characters>

Comment: I have tried this solution and it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code, and it will do the trick :)

editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);

This will show the the numeric keypad first, but also allows you to enter free text.

More information tap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216169/numeric-soft-keyboard-on-android/3772860#3772860)

This problem is similar to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153796/how-do-i-default-to-numeric-keyboard-on-edittext-without-forcing-numeric-input).

Comment: For me it is openned the numeric keaypad and I don't have the option to change to the text keypad... :(