# How to make a numpad similar layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How do i make the numpad layout as shown in the uploaded picture.
[image: Numpad]

This is my current code which would not show anything in the design view. I used this code previously on other views which work but this time it does not work and none of the buttons were visible at all in the design view.And also how do i make the 0 button as it is in the picture. This is my 2nd time asking questions in stackoverflow so do let me know if my questions are not clear and also english is not my first language. Thank you in advanced!

Edit: I have to make this layout through xml coding and not the usual thing 
      where the users click on the textview and the numpad of the phone 
      shows up. I hope this clarify the doubts of my question. I have to 
      make the clear, cancel and exit button as well.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:weightSum="4"
          android:layout_weight="4"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".insert_amount">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Display ID"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/content_box"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/in"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top Up Amount (IN)"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewnumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="0.00"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/login_signoutbutton"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/login_signoutbutton"
            android:text="2"
            />'

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/login_signoutbutton"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="3"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonclear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/login_signoutbutton"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_button"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numeric Soft Keyboard on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216169/numeric-soft-keyboard-on-android)

Comment: I have edited my questions and i hope this clarify your doubts on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Player"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="12345679"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/kid_goku" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Top up Amount" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="Top up Amount" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="4" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="7" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="2" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="5" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="8" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="0" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="3" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="6" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="9" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#9b5006"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_camera"
                    android:text="Clear"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#9b5006"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_camera"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#9b5006"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_camera"
                    android:text="Next"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your layout height exceeding the device display. You have to use ScrollView here. Also for making the number keypad using GridLayout [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677) will be better choice and you can easily get '0' button position using this view.